# Amcharts show/hide custom image bullet

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a problem with amchart schedule.
I have a line chart consisting of two lines, this is selling and buying.
There are also 4 buttons that change the display period, in the example I removed them, it does not play a role.
There are custom points that I want to show in pairs (for each line) when hovering and hide when focus out.
What is the mono property to set Hide initially and then(blur or focusOut) change it on Show?
[When hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSDGV.png)

```js
    am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart
        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
        chart.padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
        var colorSale = "#75af26";
        var colorBuy = "#269cb5";
// Load external data
        var data = [];
        var price1 = 100;
        var price2 = 150;
        var quantity = 1000;
        for (var i = 15; i < 30; i++) {
            price1 += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);
            price2 += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);

            if (price1 < 100) {
                price1 = 100;
            }

            if (price2 < 100) {
                price2 = 100;
            }


            quantity += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 500);

            if (quantity < 0) {
                quantity *= -1;
            }
            data.push({ date: new Date(2000, 0, i), price1: price1, price2:price2, quantity: quantity });
        }


        chart.data = data;

// the following line makes value axes to be arranged vertically.
        chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";

// uncomment this line if you want to change order of axes
//chart.bottomAxesContainer.reverseOrder = true;

        var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
        dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location =  -0.001;
        dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
        dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
        dateAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;
        dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.99;
        dateAxis.keepSelection = true;
        dateAxis.renderer.fontSize = "13px";
        dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#767676");
        dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.fill = am4core.color("#d8d8d8");
        dateAxis.minHeight = 30;


        dateAxis.groupData = true;
        dateAxis.maxZoomLevel = 0;



        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
        valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
        valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
// height of axis
        valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(65);
        valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
        valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
        valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
        valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.padding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#767676");
        valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.fill = am4core.color("#d8d8d8");


        valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "13px"
        valueAxis.renderer.fontSize

        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series.dataFields.valueY = "price1";
        series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
        series.name = "MSFT: Value";
        series.strokeWidth = 3;
        series.stroke = am4core.color(colorSale);
        series.tensionX = 0.77;
        series.defaultState.transitionDuration = 0;



// volume should be summed
        var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series2.dataFields.valueY = "price2";
        series2.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
        series2.name = "MSFT: Value";
        series2.strokeWidth = 3;
        series2.stroke = am4core.color(colorBuy);
        series2.tensionX = 0.77;
        series2.defaultState.transitionDuration = 0;

        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();


        var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
        var image1 = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
        image1.href = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg/620px-Approve_icon.svg.png";
        image1.width = 50;
        image1.height = 50;
        // image1.hide();
        image1.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        image1.verticalCenter = "middle";
        // image1.y = 10;

        var bullet2 = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
        var image2 = bullet2.createChild(am4core.Image);
        image2.href = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg/620px-Approve_icon.svg.png";
        image2.width = 50;
        image2.height = 50;
        // image2.hide();
        image2.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        image2.verticalCenter = "middle";
        // image2.y = 10;

        bullet.events.on("over", handleImageOver);
        function handleImageOver(event) {

        }

        bullet2.events.on("over", handleImageOver);
        function handleImageOver(event) {

        }


        // Make a panning cursor
        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
        chart.cursor.behavior = "none";
        

    }); // end am4core.ready()
```

```css
#chartdiv{
   height: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

And there’s one more thing, maybe someone knows if it’s possible to make the top and bottom of the graph so that the images can be on top of the graph
[the image is cropped by the borders of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z5Tt.png)